# Crear valida javascript en pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf

Buenas necesito ayuda con un pdf tengo 5 campos en fila son tipo menú con los mismo valores en lista de nombres y quiero seleccionar un valor en los campo tipo menú pero que se evite que se repitan los valores en los siguientes campos, que se un valor irrepetible en cada menú para se precisos, si alguien me puede guiar se lo agradecería o si tiene un ejemplo.

Comment: Por favor, incluye tu codigo para que podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Puedes mostrar que has intentado como lo has hecho creo un ejemplo minimo para que te podamos ayudar, pasate por el [tour] y por [ask]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. lee cómo crear una buena pregunta. Debes editar tu pregunta con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Debes agregar mas código. ¿qué usaste para lograr la funcionalidad que mencionas? edita tu pregunta.